# ¿error Access denied 1011 al obtener una imgen con file_get_contents?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, curl

Quisiera saber por que no puedo acceder a la imagen y mostrarlo , cada vez que ejecuto el script no se muestra la imagen y cuando lo abro desde mi host me sale lo siguiente:

> Error 1011 Ray ID: 2c82fb8597081629 • 2016-07-25 22:17:31 UTC
>
> Access denied

```
<?php
include 'dom.php';
$hi = file_get_contents("http://www.tumangaonline.com/api/v1/subidas?itemsPerPage=50&page=2&ultimasFilter=");
$ho = json_decode($hi);

    $c = 1;
    foreach ($ho->data as $key => $value) {
        ///muestro el nombre
        echo ($c++)." --> ".$value->capitulo->tomo->manga->nombre."<br>";
        // no me muestra la imagen me sale como si el link estuviera roto pero si lo abro desde la web misma oficial normal ingresa....

        echo "<img src='http://img1.tumangaonline.com/".$value->capitulo->tomo->manga->imageUrl."'> <br>";
        //muestro el capitulo 
        echo "Capitulo  --> ".$value->capitulo->numCapitulo."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: Hola amigo, me gustaría sugerirte que mires los permisos de las carpetas y desde la sesión/programa/carpeta que estas ejecutando tu código. Por mi experiencia en los ultimos 3 años, el 90% de los casos que he visto "acceso denegado, denegacion de peticion" y mensajes similares, corresponden a problemas de permisos :). ¿Qué sistema operativo usas?. Por otro lado hace poco resolví una duda similar. Pasate por https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107046/guardar-archivos-en-una-carpeta-nueva-python/107058#107058. Si tu  sistema operativo es linux. chequea propietario y permisos de ejecución

Answer (score 1):

Es un error que muestra el servicio de seguridad Cloudflare, para evitar que utilicen el contenido( .jpg, .gif, .png, .json, etc) de un sitio web en otro sitio, a veces las primeras consultas te permite consumir el contenido pero si abusas te bloquean definitivamente.

Te dejo el significado del error:

"El propietario del sitio tiene una función de seguridad activada que no permite hotlinking de ese recurso en particular . CloudFlare no puede eliminar esta opción de seguridad para el propietario del sitio , por lo que debe ponerse en contacto con el propietario del sitio directamente con alguna preocupación acerca de hotlinking"

Para mas información.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171966-1011-Error-Access-Denied-Hotlinking-Denied-

Comment: Pero hay alguna forma de evitarlo? o es imposible ? psdt: gracias por responder