# Guardar archivos en una carpeta nueva python

Tags: python, csv

```
folder = "C:\Users\Martin\Downloads\WL tags"
df = pd.read_csv("Tags para Mandar WL.csv",  header=0,  sep = ",")
for i, g in df.groupby('Inventory Name'):
    g.to_csv(folder, '{}.csv'.format(i.split('/')[0]), index=False)
```

Quiero guardar mis archivos creados en la siguiente carpeta y no puedo hacerlo ya que me sale este error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Martin\\Downloads\\WL tags'
```

Comment: Es posible que desde donde se ejecuta el código le falten permisos sobre la carpeta o ruta destino. Es decir, el programa no tiene permiso para acceder a esa ruta. Saludos!

Comment: Si, pienso que es eso pero como puedo darle esos permisos?? @Minerillo

Comment: Que sistema operativo andas?

Comment: Windows 10 y Mac Capitan. Para ambos necesitaría

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues a ver, tu respuesta necesita de saber algo mas, ya que consideraría irresponsable por mi parte decirte que le des permisos "a tope", sin tu saber que estás realizando exactamente. Por ello, lo primero que te recomiendo es aprender sobre los permisos de las carpetas en los sistemas operativos.

De forma general, cada directorio tiene permisos de "lectura, escritura y ejecución". A su vez tienen "propietarios", es decir, que usuario o grupo de usuarios pertenece ese directorio.

En tu caso, lo que buscas modificar son permisos sobre "lectura, escritura y ejecución" de ese directorio donde vas a guardar.

Aquí dejo ambos enlaces de como hacerlo en ambos SO.

MAC:
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25287?locale=es_ES

WINDOWS:
https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc754344(v=ws.11).aspx

Espero que sea tu solución =)